# Android audio player not play like whatsApp audio player

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

**when i am play audio player and between playing i am play second audio first audio progress bar and timer sink with second audio player and so on .** please help on this .**All audio are loaded in recyclerview.**I want audio Player like whatsapp play audio one by one and there progress bar no sink with each other

```
  if (message.getFileType() == MessageFileType.AUDIO)
        {
            mediaUrl=message.getFile();

            Log.d("tag","mediaURL"+mediaUrl);
            Uri video = Uri.parse(mediaUrl);

                holder.BtnPlayMusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        holder.BtnPlayMusic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button_red);

                        if(flag){

                            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, video);
                            flag = false;
                        }
                      if ( mPlayer.isPlaying())
                        {
                            holder.MusicSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                            mPlayer.stop();

                            flag=true;
                            // mPlayer.reset();
                            holder.BtnPlayMusic.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_red);

                                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, video);
                                flag = false;

                            mPlayer.start();
                            holder.BtnPlayMusic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button_red);
                            getDurationTimer(holder);
                            holder.MusicSeekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
                            getSeekBarStatus(holder);
                         }
                       else
                        {
                                    mPlayer.start();
                                    getDurationTimer(holder);
                            holder.BtnPlayMusic.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_button_red);
                            holder.MusicSeekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration()/1000);
                                    getSeekBarStatus(holder);


                            mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    holder.BtnPlayMusic.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_red);
                                    flag=true;
                                    holder.MusicSeekBar.setProgress(0);

                                }}); }}
                });

                holder.BtnStopMusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                            mPlayer.stop();
                        mPlayer.reset();
                            flag=true;
                            // mPlayer.reset();
                            holder.BtnPlayMusic.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_button_red);


                    }
                });

        }
```

```
 //Creating duration time method
    public void getDurationTimer(MessageViewHolder holder){
        final long minutes=(mPlayer.getDuration()/1000)/60;
        final int seconds= (int) ((mPlayer.getDuration()/1000)%60);
        holder.MusicTime.setText(minutes+ "0:0"+seconds);


    }



    //creating a method for seekBar progress
    public void getSeekBarStatus(MessageViewHolder holder){
        thread=new Thread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               int currentPosition = 0;
               int total = mPlayer.getDuration();
               holder.MusicSeekBar.setMax(total);
               while (mPlayer != null && currentPosition < total && flag==false) {
                   try {
                       Thread.sleep(1000);

                           currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();


                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       return;
                   }
                   holder.MusicSeekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
               }
           }
       });
        thread.start();

        holder.MusicSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progress=0;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(final SeekBar seekBar, int ProgressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    mPlayer.seekTo(ProgressValue);//if user drags the seekbar, it gets the position and updates in textView.
                    progress=ProgressValue;
                }
                final long mMinutes=(ProgressValue/1000)/60;//converting into minutes
                final int mSeconds=((ProgressValue/1000)%60);//converting into seconds
                holder.MusicTime.setText(mMinutes+"0:0"+mSeconds);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                mPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: getSeekBarStatus  function is not working properly can you please check